# What is the library rpw and what is use for?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello I have found in a code, that I just got from a former colleague this  line

from rpw.utils import gen_engine

I see that the library is used to create the connection that allow to insert a df in a sql table:

FIRST

```
engines = {
        'core': gen_engine('DRIVER={driver};SERVER={ip};DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=Yes'.format(**connections['1']), False),
        'raw': gen_engine('DRIVER={driver};SERVER={ip};DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=Yes'.format(**connections['2']), True),
        'mga': gen_engine('DRIVER={driver};SERVER={ip};DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=Yes'.format(**connections['3']), True),
    } 

connections = {
    'coredb': {
        'driver': '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
        'ip': 'ip',
        'database': '1',
    },
    'raw_bq': {
        'driver': '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
        'ip': 'ip',
        'database': '2',
    },
    'marketing': {
        'driver': '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
        'ip': 'ip',
        'database': '3',
    },
}
```

THEN

```
df.to_sql(
            'TableName',
            schema = 'dbo',
            con = engines['mga'],
            index = False,
            if_exists = 'append',
        )
```

I understand what the code does, and I was able to reproduce the same using SQLAlchemy and pyodbc that are more familiar for me. But still, I would like to have more information about the library. I have been searching, but I can not find something like this, I found this

https://github.com/gtalarico/revitpythonwrapper

But I am not sure if they are the same.

So in summary if someone has more information or can give me some idea about the library it would be very good

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://revitpythonwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb, yes it is in the requirements.txt files, I tried to install it using pip and Conda, but I did not find a package with the name rpw

Comment: I read the documentation (no in detail so far ) , but I could not find any module like gen_engine in rpw.utils in my first read